# How does Instagram know my location even if I use VPN and have no sim card?

Tags: privacy, vpn, account-security, facebook, geolocation

I'm using this Instagram account only on my 2nd phone which has no sim card and airplane mode always on. I use VPN 100% of the time when connecting to the internet. The account isn't linked with any Facebook account.

When I checked Instagram Setting > Security > Login Activity, it shows the VPN location. However, when looking at Setting > Account > About Your Account > Account Based In, Instagram still shows that my account is based in my real location, not the VPN location.

How can Instagram detect this when I try every way to hide my real location?

Comment: You can't have "airplane mode always on" and still access the Internet ...

Comment: My Insta does not have that section in Settings. There could be a number of ways the app got your real location, mostly from the device itself (timezone, registered wifi location, etc.)